# java develop multi database listener application

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have two applications running their own databases.

I want to make a middle layer service that can sync both databases.

If one application makes some update in its database,then middle layer application should update another application's database and vice-verse.

Is there any hibernate solution for this thing or any other java based solution?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: you can implement Master-Slave relationship between both database.

Comment: Do you mean that whenever you make any changes in database, the database should notify to the java service? if this is the case i doubt if its possible. Think about adding a new layer, and both your applications makes calls to this service to make changes in the database. This way you have all the control you need.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani : Does it matter? I am not sure but it should be mysql.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati : No,i cann't make any change in database structure of either application.

Comment: @varun : yes, you are right,As you told about application's call,i want to avoid writing any sync code in either application.

I am more interested in first thing i.e. notify a third java application on database change.

Comment: Even if somehow you manage to notify your service about the change, how you will find out what changes are made, I suppose you think of writing some type of trigger in both databases to sync other database, I am not really a db person so cant suggest much. Still if you want to do this using java I still suggest to write a service which runs on server and this should be the only way both your applications can interact with the database.

Comment: yes, i am going to develop that middle layer java service,the question is how this java layer come to know about database changes.

One solution is somehow we can develop some database listener in java(in middle layer application) that can listen every database change.

Second solution is to have interaction through some web services among all three applications but i don't want to write any thing in either application,that's the main issue.